# Authentication in Aspnet mvc 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to develop a small web application in asp.net mvc4 c#.

I created with Visual Studio web application who contain already functional authentication .

Here is the models :

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mémoriser le mot de passe ?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "La chaîne {0} doit comporter au moins {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe et le mot de passe de confirmation ne correspondent pas.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         //Some code here
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new {Email = model.Email});
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        //Some code here
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe rentré est incorrect.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

So When a user signs up, he enters his NAME, his Email and password.

For example, suppose I signup.

NAME: Myname
EMAIL: mystartup@sanandreas.us
Password: ******

To Login, I should provide the sames informations that I provided when i signed up. So here:

NAME: Myname
Password: ******

My problem :

To LogIn, when I put NAME: Myname and correct password, the authentication is successful, BUT when I put "Myname" or "mYname" or ... or MYNAME authentication is also successful. I JUST want to know WHY ? (i already fix this problem, i just want to know why.). Is it the same thing for everybody when we start web application with Visual Studio ?

Note that the user that i created (user : Myname) it's the only one user of table UserProfiles.

Thank you.

Comment: Refer [Membership.ValidateUser method ignores case](http://forums.asp.net/t/1273699.aspx?Membership+ValidateUser+method+ignores+case)

Comment: You said this is MVC 4 in your title, and C# 4 in your question, but did you know that .NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, and C# are all versioned differently?

Comment: @Mason, it's just a mistake, yes i know. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.